# Using Python to check website for status changes

Tags: python, html, bots

so I want to create a program that will check a specific website https://www.recreation.gov/camping/campgrounds/232463/availability for available camping spaces for a specific range date. If a campsite is available it will show as "A" and if it is not then it will either show "X" or "R". Throughout the day if people cancel sites will become available and the status will change to "A". I'm trying to determine if there's a way to create a program with Python that will check lets say every 5-10 minutes for the page to show if any spots change to an "A" and notify me.

I've done some searching around but as I'm quite new to Python I don't really know the keywords I should be searching for to get to a solution. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: might be part of their api offerings https://www.recreation.gov/use-our-data

Comment: First you should maybe start to look into [web scraping](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-web-scrape-with-python-in-4-minutes-bc49186a8460) with tools like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) so you can actual fetch the data. There may even be a api that the park uses. After that you should learn about data structures so you know what would be the best data structure to store your data.